# Motorola FX9500 Rfid reader and LLRP

Tags: rfid

We are trying to integrate FX 9500 reader in our product support.  For this we are trying to test LLRP support of this reader using LLRPHelloWorld program from llrp group.  But it fails to respond with non optional parameter.

Source code of program:
http://pastebin.com/NyTksZjv

Log4J Log:

http://pastebin.com/B9HivVDQ

Few inputs:

- from manual it looks like reader requires login command (which may not be supported by LLRP. I am not sure about it)
- Currently executing this program on Mac OS X and would like to run it on Raspberry pi.

Please guide.

Comment: A couple of things: (a) Your code is in PasteBin, which some people cannot access (due to firewalls, etc). (b) The code you link to is 602 lines long, which is way longer than I imagine you'd want to wade through if you were in our position. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some tips on reducing the code down and therefore increasing your chances of getting help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to need write report after the startRoSpec then you get tagids.

```
START_ROSPEC startROSpec = new START_ROSPEC();
startROSpec.setROSpecID(new UnsignedInteger(ROSPEC_ID));
write(startROSpec, "START_ROSPEC");         
// wait for five seconds for tag reads      
pause(5000);


ENABLE_EVENTS_AND_REPORTS report = new ENABLE_EVENTS_AND_REPORTS();
write(report, "ENABLE_EVENTS_AND_REPORTS");
```

You can get class from : https://github.com/kaansey/JAVA-LLRP-RFIDTags